# Disable Ajax call with rails link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I cannot disable JQuery mobile Ajax call for a `link_to`.

I have a link with a redirect

```
 <%= link_to 'test',  my_post_path, :method => :post, "data-role" => "button", "rel" => "external", "data-ajax"=>"false", "data-inline" => "true", "data-icon" => "plus",  "data-iconpos" => "left" %>
```

This is traslated in the following html

```
<a href="/my_post" data-ajax="false" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-inline="true" data-method="post" data-role="button" rel="external nofollow">test</a>
```

my_post is just a redirect to

```
   def my_post
      redirect_to another_method_path(....)
    end
```

I tought that setting `data-ajax=false` would have been sufficient to disable Ajax for this link, but it is not. `another_method_path` is called first, leaving me with `my_post_path`.

If I disable Ajax totally

```
 $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

It is working as expected.

Am I doing something wrong in the localise `link_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that setting `rel: :external` on the link should do the trick already.

see the section "Linking without Ajax" here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

i guess that the problem is `:method => :post` in your link, as this will only work with forms or ajax.

Comment: thanks. It was the :post indeed! changing the link to a normal one (and the post to a form) it worked